# Deciding if numbers can be written as the sum of three squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, sums-of-squares

I am asked to decide if 154, 155 and 156 can be written as the sum of three squares. I am using the theorem that if $n\in S_3$ then $n\not= 4^e(8k+7)$. Now just looking at all of these numbers it doesn't seem to me that there is a way for any of them to be written this way so I think they must all $\in S_3$? Is this correct? Is there a specific way to show this or would have have to write out all possibilities such as $4^0(8(19)+2)...4^1...4^2$ for each?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the deep theorem (whose proof is very far from being trivial, relying on Lagrange's identity for quaternions)

> Every number that is not of the form $4^m(8k+7)$ is the sum of three
>   integer squares

to check if $154,155,156$ are $\square+\square+\square$ is straightforward.

1. $154=2\cdot 77$, hence $\nu_2(154)$ is odd and there are no issues;
2. $155$ is odd and $\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, no issues;
3. $156=4\cdot 39$ and $39\equiv 7\pmod{8}$, hence $156\neq \square+\square+\square$.

Answer (score 0):

For the first two numbers, you certainly can't apply that result and as a matter of fact, you could easily check that 154=144+9+1 and 155=121+25+9. For the third one, you might want to think about the fact that $156=4 \cdot 39 = 4 \cdot (8\cdot4 + 7)$.

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$
3^2+8^2+9^2 = 154,
$$
and
$$
5^2+7^2+9^2 = 155.
$$
$156$ is [not a sum of three squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_three-square_theorem), since $156 = 4\cdot(8\cdot4+7)$.

Answer (score 0):

Answers just show how the numbers can be written as desired. In practice:

1. count and remove each factor of 4 (i.e. while last two digits are divisible by 4, add 1 to the tally for e and reduce the number by 4)
2. divide by 8 to get k and find the remainder
3. the number is now $4^e(8k+r)$. If $r$ is 7 the number cannot be written as a sum of 3 squares.

It also cannot be written as a sum of 3 *positive* squares if $r$ is $0$ or $8k+r$ is in {1, 2, 5, 10, 13, 25, 37, 58, 85, 130, $a_{11}$} where $a_{11}$ (if it exists) is a number greater than $5 \cdot 10^{10}$ (see [here](https://oeis.org/A000408)).

Comment: Why do you need to count the factors of $4$? Just remove them!

Comment: If you want to represent the number as stated in the OP you need $e$. If you only care about the result, then just remove all but one factor of 2 from even numbers.

Comment: That doesn't work. You have to remove an _even_ number of factors of $2$.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. I agree.